# How to define a record field as an array in f#?

Tags: arrays, f#, record

I want to create a record field of type byte array with 8 elements but couldn't figure out the correct syntax.

I did something like:

```
let dataRecord = {
    id : int
    data : byte array 
}

let dataValues : byte array = Array.zeroCreate 8

let myArray = { id = 0; data = dataValues }
```

Can it be done in the record definition? How?

My example, above, seemed to work but I don't know if it is safe or the best or most correct way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with what you're currently doing (other than that your type definition is using `let` instead of `type`), so it's not completely clear to me what you're asking for.  Maybe something like this?

```
type dataRecord = {
    id : int
    data : byte array
}

let myRecord = { id = 0; data = [| for i in 1 .. 8 -> 0uy |] }
```

You could also just use `{ id = 0; data = Array.zeroCreate 8 }` if you'd like - array literals are often a bit easier to read, but `zeroCreate` is probably more efficient if you're creating big arrays.

Comment: "let" was a mistake I had it correct in my code but when simplifying for this example, I messed up. :-)    Thanks for the help!